# How to represent nulls in DataSets consisting of list of case classes

Tags: scala, apache-spark, null, case-class

I have a case class

```js
final case class FieldStateData(
    job_id: String = null,
    job_base_step_id: String = null,
    field_id: String = null,
    data_id: String = null,
    data_value: String = null,
    executed_unit: String = null,
    is_doc: Boolean = null,
    mime_type: String = null,
    filename: String = null,
    filesize: BigInt = null,
    caption: String = null,
    executor_id: String = null,
    executor_name: String = null,
    executor_email: String = null,
    created_at: BigInt = null
)
```

That I want to use as part of a dataset of type Dataset[FieldStateData] to eventually insert into a database. All columns need to be nullable. How would I represent null types for numbers descended from Any rather than any string? I thought about using Option[Boolean] or something like that but will that automatically unbox during insertion or when it's used as a sql query?

Also note that the above code in not correct. Boolean types are not nullable. It's just an example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are correct to use **Option** Monad for in the case class. The field shall be unboxed by spark on read.

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.{Encoder, Encoders, Dataset}

final case class FieldStateData(job_id: Option[String],
                                job_base_step_id: Option[String],
                                field_id: Option[String],
                                data_id: Option[String],
                                data_value: Option[String],
                                executed_unit: Option[String],
                                is_doc: Option[Boolean],
                                mime_type: Option[String],
                                filename: Option[String],
                               filesize: Option[BigInt],
                               caption: Option[String],
                               executor_id: Option[String],
                               executor_name: Option[String],
                               executor_email: Option[String],
                               created_at: Option[BigInt])
implicit val fieldCodec: Encoder[FieldStateData] = Encoders.product[FieldStateData]

val ds: Dataset[FieldStateEncoder] = spark.read.source_name.as[FieldStateData]
```

When you write the `Dataset` back into the database, `None` become **null** values and `Some(x)` are the values that are present.